# beautifulsoup parse python working with table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

a table looks like this

```
<tbody>
<tr class benefit-num="55"></tr>
<td class="begin-datetime">2018-11-27 12:00</td>

<tr class benefit-num="56"></tr>
<td class="begin-datetime">2018-11-27 18:00</td>
```

I have to delete specific begin-datetime table on website
I can do it by
s.

let's assume that I have to del a benefit with datetime 2018-11-27 18:00
the promotion_name is fixed stuff so you don't have to care abt it but i have to get promotion no which is 56

```
del_data = {'benefit_name[]':'promotion_name',
            'benefit_no[]':del_promotion_no}
s.post('https://sixrecipe.cafe24.com/exec/admin/promotion/benefitdel', data=del_data)
```

so i have del code but how do I get datetime 2018-11-27 18:00's benefit no?

```
del_promo_begin_datetime = 2018-11-17 18:00
for list in soup.find_all('td',{'class':'begin-datetime'}):
    promo_begintimedate = list.text
    if promo_begintimedate == del_promo_begin_datetime
        #and what?
    print(promo_begintimedate)
```

above is what i tried but I think i'm totally wrong....

Comment: I'm learning further abt beautifulsoup and i think, to solve this, i have to use next_siblings or decendants.

Comment: above all, i wonder if you logged in? You can not do such action if you are anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
del_promo_begin_datetime = '2018-11-17 18:00'

for list in soup.find_all('td',class_='begin-datetime'):
    promo_begintimedate = list.get_text()

    if promo_begintimedate == del_promo_begin_datetime:
    #and what?
        print(promo_begintimedate)
```